# Why would some non-English characters be not recognized by Oracle DB?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following query ran in my DB:

[image]

In webpage https://dbfiddle.uk/ the same query is shown like this:

[image]

Why is it that the same query, ran in my DB, is unable to recognize the last values (Turkish & Polish), while in the webpage it is complete? Is there something missing to be adjusted?

My DB version is:
"Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.15.0.0.0".

Edit 1 - National Character:
*This threw weird results.*
[image]

Edit 2 - Character Set

- My DB Character Set: WE8ISO8859P1.
- DBFiddle Character Set: AL32UTF8.
- SQL Developer Character Set: I changed it to *X-UTF-32BE-BOM* with no success.

I'm not sure what is the implication of updating the Character Set, but...

```
ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET 'AL32UTF8';
```

... threw me "ORA-24329: invalid character set identifier".

Comment: Have you tried a _national character_ literal, i.e. `N'some Turkish and Polish characters'`?

Comment: Among the possible answers, there may be a problem either with the database character set (what is your db character set?) or with the character set on your client side (where you are running SQL Developer, if I am seeing it correctly), or sometimes both. If the database character set is not large enough, the db itself may not recognize the characters. Otherwise, nothing is wrong on the db end, but the client character set - which is asked to display the characters on screen - does not understand the last characters.

Comment: What is the database character set?

Comment: In SQL Developer, go to Tools->Preferences->Environment and check/change the 'Encoding' option - either to match your database character set, or to 'UTF-8'. (You may need to restart SQL Developer, or at least reconnect; I can't remember if it takes effect immediately...)

Comment: Thanks @mathguy & others. I did add the Character Set Information in the main question.

Comment: What happens if you try what jarlh suggested - that is, run exactly your original query, but add an `N` in front of the single-quoted string (the string of characters with diacritics)? An expression of the form `N'abcd'` means "string `abcd` in the national character set". If indeed your database character set is ISO8859-1, then it doesn't support the Turkish and Polish characters you mentioned. The national character set may be a form of Unicode, and that will support all characters. Give it a try and report back, then we can take it from there.

Comment: @mathguy, I was able to run the query ´´´SELECT N'ą ę' FROM DUAL;´´´ without any issues. Not sure if I can concatenate "N" to a field instead of a set of characters.

Comment: If by "field" you mean column in a table, then for the column to be able to hold such values without corrupting them, the column must be declared to be in the national character set. For example, instead of `varchar2(200)`, the data type must be `nvarchar2(200)`. Instead of `clob` it would have to be `nclob`. You do need to read about these data types (notice the leading "n" in the name of the data type) if you must store those characters, and the db character set doesn't support them.